# R Magnifying Glass Effect

Tags: r

Is there a magnifying glass function in r?  I have a graph with a lot of info and was wondering if there is a way to expand the area around the mouse.

Comment: There's `raster::zoom`, but works only on plots of rasters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a variety of half answers:

1. [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/) supports a zoom feature for existing plots
2. You can set the xlim and ylim in a plot that is already made (assumes the plot didn't take a long time to generate), e.g. `plot(1:10, xlim = c(3,5), ylim = c(4,6))`
3. You can save your plot to a scalable device and zoom in another program, ala `pdf()`.
4. Look at the help page for `getGraphicsEvent()`. This may be platform dependent, but the code there outlines this to some extent.

There are likely some new things in the works based on Qt and/or RGGobi that may be possible too.

Answer (score 2):

There's also 'iplots extreme', aka 'Acinonyx', which is available from R-forge. Its still a bit experimental and may crash your R session though. Has zooming and linking facilities.

Answer (score 2):

I think iPlots is your best bet.  Supports dynamic zoom (i.e. click and drag zoom boxes).  I've tried using Acinonyx and had a lot of issues with bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The `TeachingDemos` package has the `zoomplot` function which will redraw the current plot with new `xlim` and `ylim`, the examples section shows using this will the `locator` function to allow you to click on 2 points in the current plot and have it replot showing just that section (zoomed in).